# Database connected for postgresql with codeigniter but, the variable db unable to connect at insert command of Blog controller

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

```
Message: Undefined property: Blog::$db

Filename: controllers/Blog.php
```

Above is the error message for not further processing db entry.

what to do at this point?

Be kind and suggest.

```
$res = $this->db->insert_string($data);
            return true;
```

Error is at the above code

rest of the code for ref:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url', 'form');
    $db = $this->load->database('db', TRUE);

    /*load Model*/
    $this->load->model('Blog');
}
```

Suggest the code to put resolve error.

Thanks.

Comment: if you don't autoload the database driver - it doesn't get assigned to the CI instance object - there are 2 options - either you autoload it or you do it manually. If you use `$this->load->database('db');` It automatically gets assigned to the CI super Object - if you dont want that - you can return it like you did - but you must assign it manually like `get_instance()->db = $this->load->database('db', TRUE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the database library in ../application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries']=array('database');
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion worked though there i landed another error but still need to be worked out.

Comment: the connection is still unable to connect because of provided setting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268984/form-submission-call-to-constructor-is-required read this question